# Is there an "AngularJs" way to move elements around the dom?

Tags: angularjs

I have a spreadsheet like table structure which the user can enter data into by clicking on the appropriate cell.  The onClick event within a table cell triggers a method which positions an input element within the same div containing the display data (using prepend), and hides the cell data by setting a `ng-hide` variable to true for the cell data selected.  When the user navigates away from the cell, the `ng-hide` variable on display div is set to false to redisplay the new value.

There is a lot of advice about not manipulating the Dom in AngularJs which I presume means not using the various jqlite or jquery methods like "prepend"  But short of moving an input cell around the spreadsheet, it seems like the more "pure AngularJS" way would be to every cell in my table contain both an input element (normally hidden) and a display div (normally displayed), with the visibility controlled by ng-if or ng-hide so that when a cell receives user focus, the display element is hidden and the input element is shown and when it loses focus, vice versa.    However, these spreadsheets (which maybe 100+ rows, and therefore 1000_ cells) will have a lot of extra hidden input elements and somehow seems sub-optimal.  But maybe that is the best way to do this in AngularJS?

Comment: The AngularJS "way" is to put an `<input ng-model="...">` element in every table cell that is an input. The model is the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

Comment: Yeah, I have a model as the single source of truth, but the input box is complex component with all kinds of magical transformations, validations and lookups going on before the model is updated.   So the short answer is, no moving a component around the webpage?